# Webdriver + HtmlUnitDriver + Java + Drop down

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver

I'm new to this forum and i'm kinda new to Selenium and everything around it. I'm a little familiar with Java, but i'm certainly not a pro

I know that there a threads like these, but still i haven't found my answer yet...
Because some of them are in C# or .NET, ... .

I'm using Webdriver and HtmlUnitDriver because i don't want Selenium to pop up a browser.
Everything has to be done in the background (don't wanna see anything, only 1 result (if everything went fine or not)).

Okay, that been said, here is the situation.
I'm checking a website, and at some point i need to select an option from a drop down list (let's say the second option).
But the problem is that this won't work...

Here is some code i'm using:

```
public class LoginLogout implements SeleniumTest{

    private WebDriver webDriver;

    @Override
    public void setUp(String baseURL){
        webDriver = new HtmlUnitDriver();
    }

    @Override
    public void invoke(){
        // Login

        webDriver.get("http://website");
        webDriver.findElement(By.name("username")).sendKeys("Dummy123456");
        webDriver.findElement(By.name("password")).sendKeys("Muddy");
        webDriver.findElement(By.className("Submit")).click();
        webDriver.findElement(By.name("/catalogue")).click();
        webDriver.findElement(By.name("/catalogue/search/synthesis/s10")).click();  
        webDriver.findElement(By.name("firstYear")).findElement(By.name("2008")).isSelected();
        webDriver.findElement(By.name("lastYear")).findElement(By.name("2008")).isSelected();
        webDriver.findElement(By.className("Submit")).click();
        webDriver.findElement(By.className("Label")).click();
    }

    @Override
    public void tearDown(){ 
        webDriver.close();
    }
}
```

Where i choose the FIRSTYEAR and LASTYEAR, that's where it's going wrong...

Can someone please help me out !!!
It would be great that i get this to work (with your help)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5):

isSelected() will only tell you if the element is already selected or not, it won't actually set anything. I believe what you want to do is cast the WebElement to a Select object which provides methods for choosing select box items.

```
Select selectBox = (Select)webDriver.findElement(By.name("firstYear"));
selectBox.selectByValue("2008");
```

You can also select by Index which I find more reliable in cases where I don't actually care which value is selected but want to ensure something is chosen.

```
selectBox.selectByIndex(0); // chooses first item.
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. when i tried -- Select selectBox = (Select)webDriver.findElement(By.name("firstYear"));
  selectBox.selectByValue("2008"); -- Eclipse underlines this part    selectByValue    and he says that "The method selectByValue(String) is undefined for the type select" what about that?

Comment: First off, are you using Selenium 2? I assumed so because you're using WebDriver. Second make sure you're importing the correct Select class, should be org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select.

Comment: Slightly different for me:  Select selectBox = new Select(webDriver.findElement(By.id(elementId)));