# Selenium WebDriver to select combo-box item?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, jbehave

We are using Selenium WebDriver and JBehave to run "integration" tests on our web-app.  I have a method that will enter a value into a form input.

```
@When("I enter $elementId value $value")
public void enterElementText(final String elementId, final String value) {
    final WebElement webElement = webdriver.findElement(By.id(elementId));
    webElement.clear();
    webElement.sendKeys(value);
}
```

But when I try to use this to select an item in a drop-down list it (unsurprisingly) fails

> java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: You may only set the value of
>   elements that are input elements

How do I select a value in the combo?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Webdriver + HtmlUnitDriver + Java + Drop down](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5805585/webdriver-htmlunitdriver-java-drop-down)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

This is how to do it:

```
@When("I select $elementId value $value")
public void selectComboValue(final String elementId, final String value) {
    final Select selectBox = new Select(web.findElement(By.id(elementId)));
    selectBox.selectByValue(value);
}
```

Answer (score 10):

The Support package in Selenium contains all you need:

```
using OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI;

SelectElement select = new SelectElement(driver.findElement( By.id( elementId ) ));
select.SelectByText("Option3");
select.Submit();
```

You can import it through NuGet as a separate package: http://nuget.org/packages/Selenium.Support

Answer (score 4):

By using ext js combobox typeAhead to make the values visible in UI.

```
var theCombo = new Ext.form.ComboBox({  
...
id: combo_id,
typeAhead: true,
...
});

driver.findElement(By.id("combo_id-inputEl")).clear();
driver.findElement(By.id("combo_id-inputEl")).sendKeys("The Value you need");
driver.findElement(By.id("combo_id-inputEl")).sendKeys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN);
driver.findElement(By.id("combo_id-inputEl")).sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);
```

---

If that doesn´t work this is also worth a try

```
driver.findElement(By.id("combo_id-inputEl")).sendKeys("The Value you need");
driver.findElement(By.className("x-boundlist-item")).click();
```

Comment: Also works in Java: given some `WebElement templateInput`, you can do `templateInput.sendKeys(STANDARD_TEXT + Keys.ARROW_DOWN + Keys.ENTER);`

Answer (score 3):

The Selenium paradigm is that you are supposed to simulate what a user would do in real life. So that would be either a click or a keys for navigation.

```
Actions builder = new Actions( driver );
Action  action  = builder.click( driver.findElement( By.id( elementId ) ) ).build();
action.perform();
```

As long as you get a working selector to feed into findElement you should have no problem with it. I have found CSS selectors to be a better bet for things involving multiple elements. Do you have a sample page?

Comment: Doesn't work for me, I can't find Actions class. BTW using selenium 2.x. But see other SO question which I have marked as duplicate.

Comment: Download the latest version. I think it used to be called ActionBuilder or something