# Selenium: To verify if an Item does not exist in combo box

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, robotframework

I am dealing with a Combo box, have to verify that an Item does not exist in combo box.
lets say Combo box has following 4 values

```
Apple

Ball

Cat

Dog
```

and **I want to verify that Elephant does not exist in combo box**..

Any help would be appreciated

Br
Sara

Comment: possible duplicate of [Selenium WebDriver to select combo-box item?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6924550/selenium-webdriver-to-select-combo-box-item)

Answer (score 0):

OK, I have found a solution myself.
Page Should Not Contain Element , keyword helps and use as follow
Page Should Not Contain Element "Xpath" (use Xpath if you have 2 argument)
xpath=//*[@id="InvestmentCollectionForm:selectedInvestmentId"]/../../td/select/option[@value='26']

Answer (score 0):

[Run Keyword And Expect Error](http://robotframework.googlecode.com/hg/doc/libraries/BuiltIn.html?r=2.8.1#Run%20Keyword%20And%20Expect%20Error) is your friend. So try to select Elephant from the combo box and expect that to fail.

Answer (score 0):

You can point combo element, get all values by tag name and search by foreach if value is there.
C#

```
public bool IsValuePresentInCombo(string comboId, string comboValue)
{
    var combo = Driver.FindElement(By.Id(comboId));
    foreach (var item in combo.FindElements(By.TagName("option")))
    {
        if (item.GetAttribute("value") == comboValue)
        {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```